# What does 'transfigure' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> McGonagall transfigured the chessmen to make them alive.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is the infinitive the result of the previous act or the object of it?
Dictionaries say that *transfigure* means "to change the appearance of something or someone" ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/transfigure)), "to change the appearance of a person or thing so that they look more beautiful" ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/transfigure)). Does the sentence mean McGonagall just changed the appearances of chessmen that are already alive, or does the word means "changing the property of something"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, the infinitive is used to express purpose or intention.

> I set out to buy food.

> To talk with an operator, press 4.

*Transfigure* means "transform into something more beautiful or elevated"; since the subject of the sentence is *chessmen* (an object) and the sentence ends with "to make them alive," the transformation to something more elevated is evident: The transfiguration changed something unanimated into something able to move, or changed an object into a living being. (Which exactly is the case should be clear from the sentences before or after that.)